# Printing documents contained in a sharepoint document library

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, customization, document-library

I need a way to print selected documents in a library from the ribbon. As I understand it, this will have to be done through scripting. So the main difficulty seems to be the fact that everything will need to be done client-side. Another not so tiny factor is that it *has* be a generic document printing button, not just for pdf or office documents.

Is there any way to tell the OS/browser to launch for each of the selected items/documents its appropriate program's printing options/window?

Also I want this to be generic to document libraries so I can't just map one as a remote disc.

Another *solution* that springs to mind is to transfer the selected documents to another document library under the care of an event handler that runs the neccessary c# commands for printing when a new item is added to said(hidden) document library.

Another thing that comes to mind is to basically reiterate what most print drivers already do with the *Print to file* option where they create a pdf document of the intended material then it would be **just** a matter of printing the created pdf. But then the printing applications already know the file they have is in the correct/accepted format and merely have to make the convertion to pdf.

Is there any way to use the OS to just open/print-to-file my document with the correct application?

Any help with the script or c# part would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Any solution to this question yet? I am in dire need of this and I'm still absolutely clueless so if you find any solution for this Please share it with me.